# How do i debounce form in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, observable, angular2-forms

I went through lots of post, but did not find what I was looking for.

Basically,

I am showing user validation on form changes. My template looks like this:

```
<div class="form-group"
      [class.error]="!loginForm.find('email').valid && loginForm.find('email').touched">
        <div class="input-wrapper">
          <input type ="email"
              class="form-control"
              id="email-input"
              placeholder="Email"
              formControlName="email">
        </div>  
        <div *ngIf="loginForm.controls['email'].dirty && !loginForm.controls['email'].valid"
          class="alert-msg">Email is invalid</div>
</div>
```

And, looking at other posts, my TS which debounces form is this:

```
this.loginForm.valueChanges.debounceTime(500).subscribe(form => {
  console.log(form, this.loginForm);
});
```

Now, the console logs are actually debouncing. But, the validation message does not debounce. It shows up straight away the message.

Is there a way to overcome this issue?

Thanks, for stopping by,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the debounceTime will only affect the code you have in the response `form => { ... }`.
So what you could do is set the validation there:

```
private loginFormIsValid:boolean;
private emailIsNotValid:boolean;

ngOnInit() {
    this.loginForm.valueChanges.debounceTime(500).subscribe(form => {
        this.loginFormIsValid = !loginForm.find('email').valid 
            && loginForm.find('email').touched;
        this.emailIsNotValid = loginForm.controls['email'].dirty 
            && !loginForm.controls['email'].valid;
        console.log(form, this.loginForm);
    });
}
```

...And then you would use it in you template as follows:

```
<div class="form-group" [class.error]="!loginFormIsValid">
    <div class="input-wrapper">
      <input type ="email"
          class="form-control"
          id="email-input"
          placeholder="Email"
          formControlName="email">
    </div>  
    <div *ngIf="emailIsNotValid"
      class="alert-msg">Email is invalid</div>
</div>
```

You can take a look at a [post on debouncing](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/01/06/taking-advantage-of-observables-in-angular2.html), it's a good example.

Comment: Yup, I eventually did this way.

Comment: can we add `debounceTime(500)` on control level ? because `this.loginForm.valueChanges.debounceTime(500)` is on form level ?

Comment: Yes, `valueChanges` can be found on `FormControl` too, which returns an `Observable` that has the `debounce()`.

Comment: @TouqeerShafi did you ever come up with a good solution for this? I'm assuming you wanted only certain controls to be debounced (eg. a text field but not a radio button)